Fluentd Geoip Plugin is not working in Amazon Linux 2023
While installing 'fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-geo' in Amazon Linux 2023, we get below errors. Is this a known issue already?
Note: Fluentd is installed using Repo (Script on website), and all dependencies are installed already.
'fluentd' version '1.16.5'
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/opt/fluent/lib "gcc -o conftest -I/opt/fluent/include/ruby-3.2.0/x86_64-linux -I/opt/fluent/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -I/opt/fluent/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I.    -O2 -ftree-vectorize -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2-Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -march=x86-64-v2 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fPIC  conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/fluent/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/fluent/lib -L. -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,-dT,/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/fluent-package-5.0.3/.package_note-fluent-package-5.0.3-1.amzn2023.x86_64.ld -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--no-as-needed   -m64   -Wl,-rpath,/opt/fluent/lib -L/opt/fluent/lib -lruby  -lm -lpthread  -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open linker script file /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/fluent-package-5.0.3/.package_note-fluent-package-5.0.3-1.amzn2023.x86_64.ld: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

I am trying to use geoip plugin in fluentd, its installed but not working.

Can someone help on this?
